# Check if a word contains one or more asterisks

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-matching, string-search

I have referred to some posts related to this on Stack Overflow.
However I did not really find a very convincing way of doing this.

How would I have a function to return True or False depending on whether a word (which is input to the function) contains 0 or 1(or more) stars.

I tried something like this:

```
def ANY_CHAR_IS_star(word):
    return bool(re.match(r"^[*]?", word))
```

However this is return true for false cases as well.
Not sure where am going wrong. A little weak on regex honestly

Comment: You regex (and `re.match`) match an asterisk only at the beginning of the word.

Comment: But _any_ string contains 0 or 1 or more stars.

Answer (score 6):

The most pythonic way of doing this would be

```
return '*' in word
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex you are looking for is probably this one `r".*[*].*"`

As Matan already mentionned, people usually use the `in` keyword to verify if a string is a substring of another one.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check the a character in string and count the occurence of that character satisfy a condition then here is a code ,

```
from collections import defaultdict

def defv():
    return 0

def func(string):
    dic = defaultdict(defv)
    for i in string :
        dic[i]+=1
    return dic

word = 'abcdef**abs**'
data = func(word)

# check *  is in word and haveing count say x then
check='*' # checking caracter
count=2
try :
    if data[check]>count:
        print('True',data[check]) # printing the number of occurence of that charater
    else:
        print('False')
except KeyError:
    print('character is not in the string.')
```